# Compiling C program: conflicting types for 'enqueue'

Tags: c, struct

I'm trying to create a Queue struct in C that will allow a custom struct to be 'enqueued' and 'dequeued'. For example, I have a Person struct:

```
struct Person {
    int personID;
    int arrivalTime;
};
```

I want to create my Queue, and I'm doing it as follows:

```
struct Queue {
    struct Person *front;
    struct Person *tail;
    int size;
};

void enqueue(struct Queue *queue, struct Person *person) {
    if (queue->size == 0) {
        queue->front = person;
        queue->tail = person;
    } else {
        queue->tail->next = person;
        queue->tail = person;
    }
    queue->size++;
}

struct Person *dequeue(struct Queue *queue) {
    if (queue->size == 0) {
        return NULL;
    } else {
        struct Person *person = queue->front;
        queue->front = person->next;
        queue->size--;
        return person;
    }
}
```

At the top of my program, I'm declaring both `enqueue` and `dequeue`, but when I try to compile, I get the error that there are conflicting types for `enqueue` and `dequeue`.

My declarations:

```
void enqueue(struct Queue *, struct Person *);
struct Person *dequeue(struct Queue *);
```

Super new to C, so help would be appreciated. Thanks!

EDIT: Full C file, as requested:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

// Queue Declarations
void enqueue(struct Queue *, struct People *);
struct People *dequeue(struct Queue *);

struct People {
    int peopleID;
    int arrivalTime;
};

struct Queue {
    struct People *front;
    struct People *tail;
    struct People next;
    int size;
};

void enqueue(struct Queue *queue, struct People *people) {
    if (queue->size == 0) {
        queue->front = people;
        queue->tail = people;
    } else {
        queue->tail->next = people;
        queue->tail = people;
    }
    queue->size++;
}

struct People *dequeue(struct Queue *queue) {
    if (queue->size == 0) {
        return NULL;
    } else {
        struct People *people = queue->front;
        queue->front = people->next;
        queue->size--;
        return people;
    }
}

    

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    printf("Main");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You may want to check the return value of your `dequeue` declaration vs. definition.

Comment: `struct Process *dequeue(struct Queue *queue)` is not the same as `void dequeue(struct Person *);`

Comment: Ah sorry I had conflicting struct types - just updated my example.

Comment: Please post the complete source file (after removing anything that does not affect the error, but making sure the error still occurs without it), so that you have a [mcve].  There may be something else in it that you are missing.  Include the complete and exact text of the error message as well.  Also, make sure this is really the file you are compiling; e.g. did you save the file in your editor before running the compiler again?

Comment: Yeah, just saved and tried to compile it. Edited my post right now to include the file, and shortened my `main` function

Comment: There is no `next` member in `People`, so what is `people->next;` doing?

Answer (score 1):

When you declare functions whose arguments or return value involve a `struct` type, that type should be declared first.

Move the declarations of `enqueue` and `dequeue` after the declarations of `struct People` and `struct Queue`.  Or, if for some reason you don't want to, then include forward declarations of `struct People` and `struct Queue` beforehand.

```
struct People;
struct Queue;

void enqueue(struct Queue *, struct People *);
struct People *dequeue(struct Queue *);

struct People {
    int peopleID;
    int arrivalTime;
};

struct Queue {
    struct People *front;
    struct People *tail;
    struct People next;
    int size;
};

...
```

You do have some other mistakes further down; the `next` member of `struct Queue` is probably supposed to be a pointer, and there are some instances where you try to access a nonexistent `next` member in `struct People`.  If you can't sort those out, please ask a separate question about them.

Comment: Ah thank you - that resolved it, I didn't realize my declarations of structs had to exist. And yeah great heads up - I had to move the `struct People *next` pointer to the `People` struct